# CSS file not working on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

Can someone please tell me why the CSS styles for this page aren't loading on Chrome? Here is the link: http://otownsend.ca/html/lokafyinfographic.html

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Page is opening absolutely fine in chrome.

Comment: try opening it in incognito mode of chrome and check.

Comment: Given wrong path for your CSS files.

Comment: your css files give 404s. check your paths

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 and go to the console tab. And you will see message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

That means your css files are unavailabe somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS loads okay. You can actually [view it here](http://otownsend.ca/css/lokafyinfographic.css).

If you open the console `F12` on Windows, you'll see the following error -

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://otownsend.ca/html/css/bootstrap.min.css`

So it looks like you either haven't included the `bootstrap.min.css` file on your server or the `href` you've provided is wrong.

Is this correct? - `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`?

Try replacing it with this - `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet">`

Similarly, it looks like you're also missing the `full-slider.css` file. Try providing the right path for your files and it should work fine.

**UPDATE -**

Looks like you're having a cache issue. There's a simple workaround to this -

Each time you make an update to your CSS file, have a new query string at the end of the file name, such as `href="../css/lokafyinfographic.css?version=1"`. If the user has `lokafyinfographics.css` cached in their browser, the user might not be able to see your latest changes. So, if you add a query string `?version=1` or so, it will force their browser to look for that file.

Unless, your server is programmed to do anything with the query string, the browser will safely ignore it but loads and caches the new CSS file. So, each time you make an update, have a new query string like `?version=2` or so in your `href`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But full-slider.css and bootstrap.min.css aren't even my main css files. My main file is "lokafyinfographic.css". I don't know why those other css files should get in the way of it loading.

Comment: I actually read somewhere to clear my browsing data and now the main css page connects in Chrome! Thanks for helping anyways :) Hopefully this problem doesn't happen again...

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend Ah, the cache issue! It is pretty common. I've updated my answer to provide a workaround. If you found the answer helpful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted!